# Magento 2.3 How to add customer login function for my existing Observer?

Tags: magento2.3, event-observer, customer, price, logging

Following are the code show  Premium or Non-Premium along with product name using observer,

```
<?php
namespace Gta\CustomerMsgPdp\Observer\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Data implements ObserverInterface
    {
        /**
         * Below is the method that will fire whenever the event runs!
         *
         * @param Observer $observer
         */
        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $product = $observer->getProduct();
            $originalName = $product->getName();
            $price = $product->getPrice();

            if($price >= '50')
            {
                $modifiedName = $originalName . ' - Premium Products';
            }
            elseif($price <= '50')
            {
                $modifiedName = $originalName . ' - Non Premium Products';
            }

            // $modifiedName = $originalName . ' - Modified by Magento 2 Events and Observers';
            $product->setName($modifiedName);
        }
    }
```

I want to add another observer to check if customer logged-in or not if customer logged-in then only show wheater it is premium or non-premium products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to check Customer is Logged in Or Not ? 
**Using Object Manager :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

**In Controller :**

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

If it's helpful please accept it.Thanks